# object::method() must be compatible with that of objectAbstract::method() - pass parameter = value?

Tags: php, oop

I am fairly new to PHP OOP and I am getting an error.

objectForm::addMessage() must be compatible with that of objectAbstractForm::addMessage() in /www/form/Form.php on line xx

I have seen this a few times where the method parameters are like $var1, $var2 = false (or null) and for whatever reason I get "must be compatible with that of X::Y()"

```
public function addMessage($message, $messageType = 'info')
{
    if (!in_array($message, $this->_messages)) {
        if ('info' == $messageType) {
            $this->_messages[] = $message;
        } else {
            $this->_errorMessages[] = $message;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm fairly new at OOP, I cannot figure out a better way for this.

**Edit:** In the parent have for example,

```
abstract class objectAbstractForm {

abstract protected function addMessage($message, $messageType);

}
```

What is a better way to do this? I am using PHP 5.2.17

Comment: Provide the function definition of the parent's `addMessage()`. My guess is your parameter count mismatches.

Comment: Thanks Jason, forgot -_- edited post.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you've made the 2nd argument optional in the child class but it's required in the parent class. If you want an optional argument, you'll need to make it optional in the parent class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your class is extending another (from the error message it's extending `objectForm` in `/www/form/Form.php`), the method signature for the `objectAbstractForm::addMessage()` (your method posted here) must be the same as `objectForm::addMessage()`.

For example:

```
class A {
    public function test($a, $b, $c=null) {
        // code
    }
}


class B extends A {
    public function test($a, $b, $c=null) {
        // code
    }
}


class C extends A {
    public function test($a, $b=null) {
        // code
    }
}
```

Class `C` will generate your error, the signature of the method `C::test()` is different from the signature in the method `A::test()`, whereas `B::test()` will be accept, because its signature is the same as `A::test()`.

I'll be more than happy to make my answer more specific to your question but you'll need to post the method signature for `objectForm::addMessage()` and the class signature for both `objectAbstractForm` and `Form`

EDIT: I had my guesses of your classes the other way around, but the principle is the same, you cannot have a mismatch of parameters in PHP 5.2. You will need to edit the signature for whichever you prefer.

Alternatively, you can upgrade to PHP 5.3 or higher and this won't nag you.

HTH

P.S.: I'm not sure if I'm using the right terminology when I say "method signature", but if I'm wrong, feel free to correct me :)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the parent example. Placed it under Edit in original post.

Comment: Thanks for the updated Edit. Both you and dnagirl's responses makes sense. Now that you mentioned it, I have neglected upgrading to PHP 5.3 on this server.

I will take your advice and make sure this doesn't arise on other instances that could be running 5.2 or older. :]